# Xcode 6.0.1 new warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I did not get this error warning until I updated to the latest version of Xcode?

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'MPNowPlayingInfoCenter' with an expression of type 'NSNotificationCenter’
```

CODE:

```
- (void)doUpdateNowPlayingCenter 
{
    if (!self.updateNowPlayingCenter || !self.nowPlayingItem)
    {
        return;
    }

    Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");

    if (!playingInfoCenter)
    {
        return;
    }

    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *center = [playingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
    NSDictionary *songInfo = @
    {
         MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: [self.nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle],
         MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: [self.nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration]
    };

    center.nowPlayingInfo = songInfo;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like some type inference got broken in XCode 6. The cast will work around the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can silent the warning by casting default center this way:

```
MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *center = (MPNowPlayingInfoCenter*)[playingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
```

Answer (score 0):

The last version is the 6.1.
Update to the lastest version.